# Should I add content with jQuery or just show/hide it when needed?

Tags: jquery, dom

There are some elements on my page that I need to show/hide often. An example is spinner/loading icons and another are modal/dialog windows.

I have read that anything triggered by jQuery should be added by jQuery. So this means I have to add/remove the spinner and dialog windows as and when they're needed.

Another option I have seen on sites like Twitter, is to load all the content as part of the initial page and then show/hide it as and when needed. This means I'll have some 10+ modal/dialog windows and possibly another 10+ spinners in various locations around the page waiting to be shown or hidden.

What would be a good approach to go for? I prefer the latter, but not if it means causing usability issues or a poor experience in loading times. But adding/removing DOM elements continuously might be resource intensive.

Comment: Don't you have a master page/something similar? Usually you'd put those on that master page, then they can get re-used by any page and not duplicated.

Comment: Seems like premature optimization. I would just place everything in the DOM hidden and show when necessary. If you find it too intense, refactor it later into a more dynamic operation.

Comment: @mattytommo I do have a master page that includes a header/footer and some other items. The reason I'd have multiple windows and spinners is because I don't want just 1 spinner on the whole site. I want to add a spinner in the location wherever an action is taking place so the user knows something is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another option I have seen on sites like Twitter, is to load all the
>   content as part of the initial page and then show/hide it as and when
>   needed.

this is the way to go, initial loading time will not be hurted much by spinners and loading gifs, but to fetch ti everytime later will sure hurt.

> I'll have some 10+ modal/dialog windows and possibly another 10+
>   spinners in various locations around the page waiting to be shown or
>   hidden.

No way that you will end up with a scenario like that unless you develop your website as a onepage, and this onepage has no proper handling of it's content, and that the content is split between multiple views (10) and each one has it's own spinner/loading content.

even if this is the scenario, you should follow the @mattytommo from the comment and add just one instance to a shared area, and show/hide it whenever you need to.